# How do I make all child <div>s expand to the length of parent div when one child causes parent to expand?

Tags: css, html, parent

I've seen this question asked a hundred times and I've tried all the solutions given and I still haven't managed to get this to work.

The problem: I have a parent DIV with four child DIVs two with content, two only for looks:

([site shadow] [left menu] [content area] [right shadow])

When the content area has enough text to expand the content area I want the right shadow and left menu graphics to expand down the page with the rest of the DIVs.

I have tried adding a clear:both to the parent div and that does nothing. I'll include the relevant code below.

I should add that the shadow on the right of the web page disappears completely when adding a height % to the parent DIV

Additionally if I add a very large height:4000px to the parent div everything cooperates like I want, although I want the site to re-size to content not just to 4000px.

The relevant HTML:

```
<div id="body_area">
  <div id="body_left"></div><!-- just a left page graphic -->

    <div id="sidebar">
      some info here
    </div>

    <div id="content_area">
      enough text here to cause the div to expand beyond browser height.
    </div>

    <div id="body_right"></div>  <!-- just a right shadow graphic -->

    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS

```
#body_area{
    overflow:auto;
    width:1024px;
    margin:0px auto;
    clear:both;
}

#body_left{
    height:516px;
    width:25px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("images/body_left.jpg") repeat-y;
    float:left;
}

#body_right{
    height:100%;
    width:28px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("images/body_right.jpg") repeat-y;
    float:left;
}

#sidebar{
    height:100%;
    width:213px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("images/side_menu.jpg") repeat-y;
    float:left;
}


#content_area{
    height:100%;
    width:758px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("images/content_area.jpg") repeat-y;
    float:left;
}


#footer{
    height:34px;
    width:1024px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:url("images/footer.jpg");
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a pure `css` solution then it'll be very difficult to achieve. But to get this done easily you can use `jQuery`.

edit: adding jquery library from a jquery cdn [this will word only when you have active internet connection-in case you didn't know it]

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var h1 = $('#sidebar').height(),
                h2 = $('#content_area').height(),
                maxNum = ( h1 > h2 ) ? h1 : h2;

            $('#body_area').css('height', maxNum);
        });
</script>
```

this works well. But there is a little problem, you have to readjust the width of the `div`s inside the `body_area` div.
Thanks

EDIT: Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lessons by Larissa</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.leigero.com/div_expanding_issue/style.css" />
        <link class='webFontsCSSLink' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa|Pacifico|Dancing+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Header area -->
        <div id="header_area">
            <div id="title_box">
                <div id="title_text"><h1></h1></div>
            </div>

            <div id="banner">
                <div id="banner_text">
                    <font color="#fff" face="'dancing script', arial, sans-serif" size="4">
                        Learning music is a motion of the mind…, a flowing of harmonious notes, on a wisp of melodious air. <p class="quote">-M.O'Malley</p>
                    </font>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="header_right"></div>
            <div id="header_left"></div>
            <div id="title_image"></div>
            <div id="nav_bar">
                <div id="nav_bar_text">
                    <!-- This is where all of your upper menu items are located. You can add more or remove the links by copying and pasting more in the appropriate sections -->

                    <ul id="nav"> <!-- This begins all the links in the top menu bar -->
                        <li class="home"><a href="http://www.leigero.com/lessons">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#blah2.html">About</a>                        
                            <ul><!--Sub menu for 'Home.' These are the links that appear when you hover over 'home' -->
                                <li><a href="#1.html">Philosophy</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#2.html">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#3.html">Add as many links as you want</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#blah3.html">Link 2</a>
                            <ul><!--Sub menu for 'Home.' These are the links that appear when you hover over 'home' -->
                                <li><a href="#1.html">Sub Link 1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#6.html">More Links </a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#6.html">More Links </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="#2.html">Sub Link 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#3.html">Sub Link 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Body area -->

        <div id="body_area">
            <div id="body_left"></div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                   <p>ASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJKJFlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                   LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    </p>

            </div>
            <div id="content_area">
                    <p>ASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF 
                    LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF LDSAfjlkdfjsldkfjsdlfkjdsljASLFKJASDFLSJDAFLSDKJF </p>

            </div>
            <div id="body_right"></div>
    <!-- Footer area -->
                <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    var h1 = $('#sidebar').height(),
                        h2 = $('#content_area').height(),
                        maxNum = ( h1 > h2 ) ? h1 : h2;

                    $('#body_area').css('height', maxNum);
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would it be complicated to do this in CSS alone? It ALMOST works as it is.

Comment: can you please try removing the css rule overflow: auto; in style.css at line 89?

Comment: I removed the overflow:auto and it had no visible affect. I also added the script into the head element of the .html page I'm assuming that's where it goes (I'm not that savvy with jquery). Also I messed around with height %ages and leigero.com/lessons has an ALMOST functioning version. but for some reason if there's too much text the divs stop expanding beyond a certain point as is visible on that page.

Comment: did you included jquery library in your page? without it, this code wont work. I'm editing my code that you can find it easy. Moreover I have created a jsfiddle based on your work and your problem. link->  http://jsfiddle.net/yXPmp/

Comment: I'm sorry for being so ignorant I know this is probably as frustrating for you as it is for me. I have added this code to the head element as is, including the src='link' and it does nothing. I viewed the jsviddle site and it works there, however, there is nothing in the html panel referencing any js at all so I'm not sure why its even running the js (I assume it just runs it automatically because that's what the program is for). I tried adding the code to my own script.js file and linked to it in the head like i did with the CSS file but I don't know how to call the function.

Comment: I tried adding the script into the html directly and it didnt work, I tried adding it to the bottom of the body tag after the layout was formed in case it was running the code before the fields were overfilled, still didnt' change anything. Basically i'm not adding the code to the right place or referencing it properly so I guess i need child-level directions on how to incorporate this. which just frustrates me to no end. (sorry again)

Comment: You don't have to be frustrated, because everyone faced same as you when they were a beginner (of course including me). Anyway I'm editing my answer again and giving you full code so that you can simply copy and paste it to make it working. If you want to know what does it works please feel free to let me know and i'll describe it as easily as possible. (you don't have to say sorry) Thanks

Comment: Thanks a million I really appreciate that. I was actually planning on getting the site put together and then starting javascript lessons so you're two steps ahead of me on the info. I got it working, but for future people, the script edits the entire body_area to a fixed height (fixed height of whatever dynamic content causes it to be) and to make everything else cooperate within body_area i just added a height:100% and it properly fills the space. I cant thank you enough.

Comment: well the 100% thing doesn't work. its best to use that script to determing which field is longer, then just add two more lines to the bottom setting all three fields (body_area, sidebar and content_area all to the same max height)

Comment: Congrats!! You figured it out yourself! Welcome to the world of a new dimension, javascript and jQuery. It'll make your site alive. The patience and time is needed to learn is really worthy. Thanks

Comment: Hey Maksdb one more question. This script works great and its worked on every page except for one. One page is merely a bunch of photos tossed into the page. for some reason the pictures don't cause the window to resize. If you refresh the window the page looks great, but delete cache and load the page for the first time and the page isn't expanding properly. Do images get loaded after the script is run? why would it do that?

Comment: sorry for being this much late. Can you please give me a link to that page? Maybe there's another script which is loading those images after the dom is loaded. It'd be better if i could see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After trying EVERYTHING (or so it seems) I finally realized that the best (and probably only) way to make 3 plus columns expand to the height of the longest column is to not use DIVs but instead use a table.

DIVs have their purpose and they're handy but a table automatically expands exactly the way I wanted DIVs to expand but a table doesnt require floats and such to be in line either. A quick table inside a DIV made that super simple

```
<div id="body_area">
    <table id="content">
        <tr>
            <td class="lmargin"></td>
            <td class="sidebar"></td>
            <td class="content_area">
                <div id="content_area_content">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="body_right"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<!-- Footer area -->
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

This way the table expands all columns of equal height and within the table data I can add another DIV to edit the margins and all the other attributes of its content.

Comment: Its true, but using table to make a layout isn't a good choice. http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

Answer (score 0):

What is your browser scope? (ie - which browsers are your visitors using?)

If you leave out IE7, you could solve the problem by using CSS tables like this...

1. Move the #footer out of the  #body-area
2. Set display: table-cell on the #body-area
3. Replace "float: left" with "display: table-cell; vertical-align: top" for the four children (#body-left, #body-right, #content-area and #sidebar)
4. Remove the heights of the four children - A nice thing about CSS tables for these types of layouts, are that the cells of a table expand vertically together

A bad thing about this solution is that it does not work in MISE7 (but you *could* serve a separate Javascript to IE7 with eg. a conditional comment if you don't want to exclude those users)

Works in "all modern browsers" (including IE8) though :)

So try it out:

```
<div id="body_area">

  <div id="body_left"></div><!-- just a left page graphic -->

    <div id="sidebar">
      some info here
    </div>

    <div id="content_area">
      enough text here to cause the div to expand beyond browser height.
      enough text here to cause the div to expand beyond browser height.
      enough text here to cause the div to expand beyond browser height.
      enough text here to cause the div to expand beyond browser height.
      enough text here to cause the div to expand beyond browser height.
      enough text here to cause the div to expand beyond browser height.
    </div>

    <div id="body_right"></div>  <!-- just a right shadow graphic -->

</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

and

```
#body_area{
    overflow:auto;
    width:1024px;
    height: 768px; /* just a sample value */
    margin:0px auto;
    clear:both;
    display: table;
}

#body_left{
    width:25px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("http://www.leigero.com/div_expanding_issue/images/body_left.jpg") repeat-y;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#body_right{
    width:28px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("http://www.leigero.com/div_expanding_issue/images/body_right.jpg") repeat-y;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#sidebar{
    width:213px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("http://www.leigero.com/div_expanding_issue/images/side_menu.jpg") repeat-y;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}


#content_area{
    width:758px;
    margin:0px;
    background:url("http://www.leigero.com/div_expanding_issue/images/content_area.jpg") repeat-y;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}


#footer{
    height:34px;
    width:1024px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:url("http://www.leigero.com/div_expanding_issue/images/footer.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is is exactly the sort of solution i was looking for. I had just fixed it with an html table and set background images to the elements, but I didn't really know about using CSS to set table properties.